# Symfony2 on Installation Demo/Config 404 Error on Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to set up Symfony2 as per the guide on their website. I'm running Apache2 on my local Ubuntu machine.

I have managed to resolve all of the errors mentioned in

localhost/Symfony/web/config.php

(which works as expected), but when I try to follow either of the links from there:

localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_configurator/   or   localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/

I get a 404 error. If I go instead to

localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php

then the page works, but then again, all links from it are broken. Could this be an Apache config issue?

Answer (score 2):

your document root of your apache should point to the web directory of symfony

if i assume the following is the path to the php file:

```
/var/www/Symfony/web/app_dev.php
```

you should point your apaches document root to:

```
/var/www/Symfony/web/
```

ensure apaches rewrite engine is on and htaccess files are correctly read.

enable apaches rewrite engine:

```
a2emod rewrite
```

if this doesn't help, try adding/moving your question to stackoverflow.com, its more a symfony specific question, there you find more symfony user.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0

Comment: Having same problem but in Nginx tried a couple of variations (root) but doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the AcceptPathInfo directive to your .htaccess or your vhost:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

This is a strange oversight in the Symfony installation / configuration guide.. It seems that the issue has been known about for a long while and yet a solution hasn't been integrated/document anywhere official.